# How to count AR point cloud number? (Unity AR Foundation 3.0.1)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have been trying to count the number of all ar point cloud collected in the AR session.

I've tried the following code, but arPointCloud keeps throwing error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I would be so happy if anyone can help me.

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;


public class PointNumberCount : MonoBehaviour
{
 ARSessionOrigin arSessionOrigin;
 ARPointCloud arPointCloud;

 int totalNumber;
 List<Vector3> featurePoints = new List<Vector3>();

 void Start()
 {

     arSessionOrigin = GetComponent<ARSessionOrigin>();

     arPointCloud = arSessionOrigin.trackablesParent.GetComponentInChildren<ARPointCloud>();
 }
 void Update()
 {

         arPointCloud = arSessionOrigin.trackablesParent.GetComponentInChildren<ARPointCloud>();
         featurePoints = new List<Vector3>(arPointCloud.positions);
         totalNumber = featurePoints.Count;

 }
}
}
```

Comment: well is `arSessionOrigin` assigned? Are you sure that this object has a `ARSessionOrigin` attached? Is further `trackablesParent` assigned correctly? Finally are you sure that `ARPointCloud` is attached on an active and enabled child? You could try to pass `true` like `arSessionOrigin.trackablesParent.GetComponentInChildren<ARPointCloud>(true);` to include inactive child objects in the search. You shouldn't do it in `Update` though .. very expensive

Comment: Actually I have no idea. I am working on ARF basic example. So what my programe does now is simple cloud point visualization and image tracking. I didn't change the structure of ARF basic example. And I am new to Unity and ARF.

Comment: I am so stupid! `arSessionOrigin` is not assigned! you are right! Thank you @derHugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the unity AR foundation 1.5.0 preview.6 and they have their own script for counting point cloud but in their script, we can't edit anything. So we need to create a custom script for counting point cloud.

Please check all the images.

[First, make sure you add you add a reference to point cloud manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuvkw.png)

[Then remove Ar point Cloud Particle Visualizer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY5dL.png)

[Attach a script and Reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqzKs.png)

Script:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
namespace UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Renders an <see cref="ARPointCloud"/> as a <c>ParticleSystem</c>.
   /// </summary>
   [RequireComponent(typeof(ARPointCloud))]
   [RequireComponent(typeof(ParticleSystem))]

   public class ARPointCloudParticleVisualizer : MonoBehaviour
   {
    public Text t;
    void OnPointCloudChanged(ARPointCloudUpdatedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var points = s_Vertices;
        points.Clear();
        foreach (var point in m_PointCloud.positions)
            s_Vertices.Add(point);

        int numParticles = points.Count;
        if (m_Particles == null || m_Particles.Length < numParticles)
            m_Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[numParticles];

        var color = m_ParticleSystem.main.startColor.color;
        var size = m_ParticleSystem.main.startSize.constant;

        for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; ++i)
        {
            m_Particles[i].startColor = color;
            m_Particles[i].startSize = size;
            m_Particles[i].position = points[i];
            m_Particles[i].remainingLifetime = 1f;
        }

        // Remove any existing particles by setting remainingLifetime
        // to a negative value.
        for (int i = numParticles; i < m_NumParticles; ++i)
        {
            m_Particles[i].remainingLifetime = -1f;
        }

        m_ParticleSystem.SetParticles(m_Particles, Math.Max(numParticles, m_NumParticles));
        m_NumParticles = numParticles;
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        m_PointCloud = GetComponent<ARPointCloud>();
        m_ParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        m_PointCloud.updated += OnPointCloudChanged;
        UpdateVisibility();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        m_PointCloud.updated -= OnPointCloudChanged;
        UpdateVisibility();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateVisibility();
    }

    void UpdateVisibility()
    {
        var visible =
            enabled &&
            (m_PointCloud.trackingState != TrackingState.None);

        SetVisible(visible);
    }

    void SetVisible(bool visible)
    {
        if (m_ParticleSystem == null)
            return;

        var renderer = m_ParticleSystem.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        t.text = m_NumParticles.ToString();
        if (renderer != null)
            renderer.enabled = visible;
    }

    ARPointCloud m_PointCloud;

    ParticleSystem m_ParticleSystem;

    ParticleSystem.Particle[] m_Particles;

    int m_NumParticles;

    static List<Vector3> s_Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    }
}
```

This is working for me.